# SpriteKit Swift animation only on one sprite at once - iOS

Tags: ios, swift, animation, sprite

I try to manage several animations for each of my sprites. The problem I have is when I select one sprite, its get animated correctly but when I choose another sprite, the animation of the first one stops and the animation begins on the second one. But I would like the animation to continue on evry sprite user touched with the finger. Here is 3 functions with the swift code:

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    let urlStr = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Video_Socle", ofType: "mov")
    let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: urlStr!)

    player = AVPlayer(URL: url)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification, object: player!.currentItem, queue: nil)
    { notification in
        let t1 = CMTimeMake(5, 100);
        self.player!.seekToTime(t1)
        self.player!.play()
    }


    videoNode = SKVideoNode(AVPlayer: player!)
    videoNode!.position = CGPointMake(frame.size.width/2, frame.size.height/2)
    videoNode!.size = CGSize(width: 2048, height: 1536)
    videoNode!.zPosition = 0


    background.addChild(videoNode!)
    videoNode!.play()



    let gestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(GameScene.handlePanFrom(_:)))
    self.view!.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
}


func handlePanFrom(recognizer : UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    if recognizer.state == .Began {
        var touchLocation = recognizer.locationInView(recognizer.view)
        touchLocation = self.convertPointFromView(touchLocation)

        self.selectNodeForTouch(touchLocation)
    } else if recognizer.state == .Changed {
        var translation = recognizer.translationInView(recognizer.view!)
        translation = CGPoint(x: translation.x, y: -translation.y)

        self.panForTranslation(translation)

        recognizer.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: recognizer.view)
    } else if recognizer.state == .Ended {

    }
}

func degToRad(degree: Double) -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat(degree / 180.0 * M_PI)
}

func selectNodeForTouch(touchLocation : CGPoint) {
    // 1
    let touchedNode = self.nodeAtPoint(touchLocation)

    if touchedNode is SKPuzzle {
        // 2
        if !selectedNode.isEqual(touchedNode) {
            selectedNode.removeAllActions()
            selectedNode.runAction(SKAction.rotateToAngle(0.0, duration: 0.1))

            selectedNode = touchedNode as! SKPuzzle

            // 3
            if touchedNode.name! == kpuzzleNodeName {
                let sequence = SKAction.sequence([SKAction.rotateByAngle(degToRad(-4.0), duration: 0.1),
                    SKAction.rotateByAngle(0.0, duration: 0.1),
                    SKAction.rotateByAngle(degToRad(4.0), duration: 0.1)])
                selectedNode.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(sequence))
            }
        }
    }
}



func panForTranslation(translation : CGPoint) {
    let position = selectedNode.position

    if selectedNode.name! == kpuzzleNodeName {
        selectedNode.position = CGPoint(x: position.x + translation.x *  2, y: position.y + translation.y * 2)

        print (selectedNode.name)
        print (selectedNode.name2)
        if selectedNode.name2 == "0" {

            Anim_Puzzle13(selectedNode)
        }

        print (selectedNode.name2)
        if selectedNode.name2 == "1" {
            Anim_Puzzle19(selectedNode)
        }

        print (selectedNode.name2)
        if selectedNode.name2 == "2" {
            Anim_Puzzle30(selectedNode)
        }

        print (selectedNode.name2)
        if selectedNode.name2 == "3" {
            Anim_Puzzle11(selectedNode)
        }

        print (selectedNode.name2)
        if selectedNode.name2 == "4" {
            Anim_Puzzle29(selectedNode)
        }

        print (selectedNode.name2)
        if selectedNode.name2 == "5" {
            Anim_Puzzle35(selectedNode)
        }

        }

}




func Anim_Puzzle13 (Node13 : SKPuzzle) {

    let puzzle13 = SKAction.animateWithTextures(sheet_puzzle13.Puzzle13_(), timePerFrame: 0.033)
    NPuzzle13 = Node13
    NPuzzle13.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(puzzle13))
    NPuzzle13.position = CGPoint(x: 500, y: 400)
    NPuzzle13.zPosition = 1

}

func Anim_Puzzle19 (Node19 : SKPuzzle) {


    let puzzle19 = SKAction.animateWithTextures(sheet_puzzle19.Puzzle19_(), timePerFrame: 0.033)
    NPuzzle19 = Node19
    NPuzzle19.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(puzzle19))
    NPuzzle19.position = CGPoint(x: 600, y: 500)
    NPuzzle19.zPosition = 1

}

func Anim_Puzzle30 (Node30 : SKPuzzle) {


    let puzzle30 = SKAction.animateWithTextures(sheet_puzzle30.Puzzle30_(), timePerFrame: 0.033)
    NPuzzle30 = Node30
    NPuzzle30.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(puzzle30))
    NPuzzle30.position = CGPoint(x: 700, y: 600)
    NPuzzle30.zPosition = 1

}

func Anim_Puzzle11 (Node11 : SKPuzzle) {


    let puzzle11 = SKAction.animateWithTextures(sheet_puzzle11.Puzzle11_(), timePerFrame: 0.033)
    NPuzzle11 = Node11
    NPuzzle11.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(puzzle11))
    NPuzzle11.position = CGPoint(x: 800, y: 700)
    NPuzzle11.zPosition = 1

}

func Anim_Puzzle29 (Node29 : SKPuzzle) {


    let puzzle29 = SKAction.animateWithTextures(sheet_puzzle29.Puzzle29_(), timePerFrame: 0.033)
    NPuzzle29 = Node29
    NPuzzle29.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(puzzle29))
    NPuzzle29.position = CGPoint(x: 900, y: 800)
    NPuzzle29.zPosition = 1

}

func Anim_Puzzle35 (Node35 : SKPuzzle) {


    let puzzle35 = SKAction.animateWithTextures(sheet_puzzle35.Puzzle35_(), timePerFrame: 0.033)
    NPuzzle35 = Node35
    NPuzzle35.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(puzzle35))
    NPuzzle35.position = CGPoint(x: 1000, y: 900)
    NPuzzle35.zPosition = 1

}
```

}

How to manage for the animation to continue on evry sprites touched and not to stop each time I touch another sprite ? I can make animation again by selecting again any sprite, but only one at a time, never more...

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct. The issue could be on your `touchesBegan` if you use this delegate method or on `UIPanGestureRecognizer`, probably you're trigger some method to remove your nodes (`node.removeFromParent()` or something like `node.removeAllActions()`). 
It's like you tap on your screen and the repeatForEver is stopped immediatly due to the node removed by the parent or all actions was stopped immediately.

If you want to stop some action it's better to give to the runAction a specific key:

```
NPuzzle30.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(puzzle30),withKey: "NPuzzle30repeatForEver")
```

and then, stop it with:

```
NPuzzle30.removeActionForKey("NPuzzle30repeatForEver")
```

**EDIT**: (after your last code update)

```
if touchedNode is SKPuzzle { 
        // 2
        if !selectedNode.isEqual(touchedNode) {
            selectedNode.removeAllActions()
            ...
            // here you remove all actions about your selectedNode, also repeatActionForever..
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. The animation stops only when I select another sprite on the screen. But I can launch it again if I select again the sprite but I can't have more than one sprite moving... Here is a more large part of my code:

Comment: I think you must search in your code all lines about "removeAllActions()" and start to debug from it. ;)

Comment: Alessandro, thanks very much ! It works !! I'm a beginner with Swift on iOS, great to have help from more experimented users.